# Can the constant of integration be imaginary?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was solving the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx} + 2y = y^2$ and got $y = \frac{2}{e^Ce^{2x}+1}$ where $C$ is the constant of integration. Values of $C$ that are imaginary, such as $C = i\pi$ are still valid solutions to the equation. I haven't found anything online about imaginary constants of integration and I've never heard of such a thing.

Also I apologize for the formatting. This is my first time using this site.

Comment: The derivative of a complex constant is zero just like a real constant. There is nothing preventing it from being complex.

Comment: If you allow only real solutions, then of course the constant is real.  But $dy/dx + 2y = y^2$ taken by itself does not specify that $y$ has real values (nor, indeed $x$).

Comment: @GEdgar That is good to know. Thank you.

Comment: Many years ago, I asked one of the early symbolic algebra programs to find $\int\sec x\,dx$. It gave me an answer that didn't look at all like the one you find in all the intro Calculus textbooks. It took me a while to see that the two expressions differed by $\pi i/4$.

Answer (score 0):

If you solve this via $u=1-2y^{-1}$,
$$
u'=2y^{-2}y'=2u,
$$
then integration after separation of variables leads to
$$
\ln|u|=2x+c.
$$
Under exponentiation the additive constant becomes a multiplicative constant, removing the absolute value results in a sign for that constant, so that, now also including the zero solution for $u$,
$$
u(x)=Ce^{2x}\implies y(x)=\frac{2}{1-Ce^{2x}},
$$
where $C$ can be any real number.

Comment: Actually, to be a little picky, the additive constant becomes a *positive* multiplicative constant $e^c$, so $C=\pm e^c$ can be any *nonzero* real number. That $C=0$ also works should be checked separately (it corresponds to the case $u=0$ that needs to be excluded when separating the variables, since you're dividing by $u$).